# Why is CSS 'ex' unit defined using the 'first available font'?

Tags: css, fonts, font-size, units-of-measurement

Why is the *em* unit defined in terms of the font actually used to render the text, and the *ex* unit using the *first available font*?

To me, that looks like the font used to compute the height of *ex* can be different from the font actually used to render the text.

Quoting the specs:

> The first available font, used for example in the definition of font-relative lengths such as ‘ex’ and ‘ch’ or in the definition of the ‘line-height’ property, is defined to be the first available font that would match the U+0020 (space) character given font families in the ‘font-family’ list (or a user agent's default font if none are available).

Why does the algorithm look for the space to compute the height of the letter 'x'? An explanation in layman terms would be very appreciated.

Comment: My guess would be to prevent relayouting from happening when a different font gets loaded. That way, your page will never be jumpy?

Comment: Didn't think of this, thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the em unit defined in terms of the font actually used to render the text, and the ex unit using the first available font?

This shouldn’t be the case: both units are intended to be relative to the current font. The definition you provided mentions “[font-relative lengths](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#font-relative-length) such as ‘ex’,” which also includes the ‘em’ unit.

That said, it seems like the authors agreed that the definition of “first available font” should be clarified: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4796

The section you quoted seem to imply that if the first font in the `font-family` list exists, but the U+0020 (space) character isn’t in the font, then the next font should be used. In practice, it sounds like browsers weren’t doing this anyway, and that probably wasn’t the original intent.

You can see the change that is being made to the definition here, as summarized in that issue: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/commit/7c2108c1764f328e0b60fffed47d3885a3dc7c11?diff=split

> Why does the algorithm look for the space to compute the height of the letter 'x'? An explanation in layman terms would be very appreciated.

For the purpose of collecting and calculating font metrics, the U+0020 space is most likely the earliest and most common code point that could contain that information and would make sense to check. Many metrics are being calculated then, like the line height and em unit, not just the ex unit.

Beyond that, [CSS ex unit section](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#font-relative-length) gives more detail on how that value is determined:

> The x-height is so called because it is often equal to the height of the lowercase "x". However, an ex is defined even for fonts that do not contain an "x". The x-height of a font can be found in different ways. Some fonts contain reliable metrics for the x-height. If reliable font metrics are not available, UAs may determine the x-height from the height of a lowercase glyph. One possible heuristic is to look at how far the glyph for the lowercase "o" extends below the baseline, and subtract that value from the top of its bounding box. In the cases where it is impossible or impractical to determine the x-height, a value of 0.5em must be assumed.

Comment: Very informative; thank you for the answer.